# MVC and EF 5 scaffolding project giving HTTP Error 400.0 - Bad Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created an MVC and EF5 scaffolding project. All the views for all tables are working except for one where it shows the index and list all entries and I am able to create new records as well but when I click on edit, details, or delete links it shows error page saying

> HTTP Error 400.0 - Bad Request Bad Request

and below that

> Most likely causes:

has nothing but a dot point in it.

I am new to this and dont know what I can do to make it work just like other pages. I did not do any programming and everything else is working fine.

The error comes on localhost as well as on remote server where I uploaded this.

**EDIT:**
Upon further investigation I found that index view has the following lines at the end, which clearly says that there is no ID being passed to the controller. Not sure what does it mean by commenting the ID part and what will go in there. My table has a composite primary key (made up of two foreign keys.

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */}) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
```

Comment: do you have a code in your controller?

Comment: Yes there is code in the controller, similar to other controllers. Index, Details, Create, Edit, and Delete.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by adding `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` to the `<modules>` tag in web.config file.

Should be something like this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        ...
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Primary Key Attribute in your database. Make sure it has one primary key attribute.

If it's missing, add it and try to regenerate the scaffolding items.